# Common scenario in Wordpress: best practices

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing a common scenario in the creation and the managing of a website that I'm still surprised I'm having difficulties in finding a good solution using Wordpress.

Let's say that I have a Wordpress website featuring food recipes. I have custom post types such as recipes and authors (of the recipes).

With the help of Advanced Custom Field plugin and Toolset plugin, it has been very easy to create the two custom post types and creating their custom fields together with the relationships between the objects.

Now, let's say that in multiple locations of the website I want to show a section called **Spotlight Recipes** where I show 3 featured recipes that I manually change every week.

What I would like to have in this situation, is a new item in the backend sidebar menu called **Website Settings** for example, that will allow me to manually choose the three recipes that will be featured in the section described above.

Let's say that I also want to display a section called **Authors of the month** and I always want to be able to manually choose the 5 authors that will be shown. It would be great if these could be also chosen inside the "Website Settings" backend page.

I think this is a very common scenario but I can't find a solution that I like. So I'm wondering: how websites using Wordpress solve this? Should I create a new custom post type called "MySettings" and create one instance of this, creating all its custom fields, and use it as a "singleton settings object"? It doesn't really appeal to me.

Answer (score 1):

The best setup would be to add a new taxonomy for your Recipe custom post type. Then create a new category in that taxonomy named "Spotlight recipes".

You can add a custom taxonomy for users also.

There could be several scenarios for limiting the number of recipes shown. If you are declaring a recipe as recipe of the week as you add it then all you would need in your widget query is 3 parameters:

1) Set category to spotlight category of new taxonomy

2) Limit posts to 3 or 4

3) Sort by most recent

This way only the most recent recipes are shown at all times. It will also let you keep an archive of recipes of the week.

Comment: And how to limit the number of the recipes in the "Spotlight recipes"?